# JS operator performance

Tags: javascript

From a performance perspective, is it better to use:

```
if (input1 === x && input2 === y || input1 === z && input2 === y) {
  // do something
}
```

or:

```
if ((input1 === x || input1 === z) && input2 === y) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: If there's any difference at all, it'd be too tiny to make a difference in all but the most exotic situations.

Comment: You can always run some tests at jsPerf

Comment: Because of the short-circuiting behavior of the logical operators, it probably depends on the frequency of values of the inputs.

Comment: Don't bother. Write the rest and then run it under a profiler and contend with the hot spots.

Comment: It's also possible that the JS compiler can detect the equivalence, and generate the same code for both.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: And you care about this because....your app is running real slow and you've identified this line is running 100 million times and is the root cause of your poor performance?

Comment: Thanks.  Sounds like it really just doesn't matter.  I'll go for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no real difference unless that script has to run trillion+ times in a loop. Write it so it looks clear & easy to read/understand.

Comment: I think you meant billion.

Answer (score 1):

Because of short-circuiting, putting the test of `input2` first is likely to be better than either of the versions you posted. If this fails, it doesn't need to test `input1` at all.

```
if (input2 === y && (input1 === x || input1 === z))
```

Swapping the order might not be appropriate if there were any side effects or order-dependencies in the test expressions. But comparing simple variables has no side effects.